# How to format decimal output in sql server select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, formatting, decimal

In my tables I have columns that is decimal (16,5). When I do

```
SELECT WorkHours, BillHours
FROM Hours
```

It gives me be that result:

```
2.00000   1.00000
2.00500   1.05000
```

How I can get back this numbers in nice looking format:

```
2       1
2.005   1.05
```

Comment: Formatting is something you should do on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROUND()` function in SQL SERVER.
However, all values in one column will have same number of decimal places.

If you want to format it further, consider client side formatting instead of writing custom server side code.